# A better way to say "enrolled in a program" to signify the difficulty of attaining admission in the face of stiff competition?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm trying to write a personal statement in which I've to account for my past educational experiences. One of my courses is from a prestigious institute in my country, where its difficult to attain admission for that particular program.

How do I say so, without mentioning that in explicitly (As space is a requirement, and also I don't want to look too smug - after all, the institutes I'm applying to are leaders in their fields, and might view it as arrogant of me) ? If I say "enrolled in the program", it may mean I simply paid the tuition fees, which is incorrect (all the students receive full scholarship by default if they pass the multiple rounds of exams, making it a much difficult feat to secure entry)....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can say that you were *selected* for the program. This implies that there was some difficult selection process to go through, after which you were a part of it.

Comment: Makes wonderful sense - I was stuck trying to look for fancy words :)

Comment: I love it when common English words are the best ways to express a difficult, specific concept.

Answer (score 4):

You can also say you were *accepted* into the program.

Comment: Thats kind of a passive word - you hardly mean to flatter when you say something is "Acceptable" :)

Comment: @shan23, the tense matters.  Indeed, it's not flattering to describe something as "acceptable".  However, it is quite normal to speak proudly of being "accepted" to a prestigious school or program.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are are looking for something in the active voice, I would suggest "gained admittance" to the program.

Comment: Even better, "gained admittance in the selection process of the Faculty"